# How to fix? Variable with is accessed from within inner class, needs to be final or effectively final

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am developing an Anti-AFK Script with Java and am running into this error.

> "Variable with is accessed from within inner class, needs to be final or effectively final"

I have searched and searched but still have no idea how to fix. Thank you for your help. Here is the script.

One more thing, this is my first post on this website, so I apologize if I missed anything. Also, if you guys want to really help me because I am stupid, how would I make the key listener class work? It has its own error of `"MKeyListener is never used"` Thanks for everything!

```
package com.plugin.TTT;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {


    Random random = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        String Switch = "Off";
        boolean test = true;
        boolean On = false;
        JFrame afk = new JFrame("Anti AFK");
        afk.setLayout(new BoxLayout(afk.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JLabel text = new JLabel("Anti AFK Program");

        JToggleButton toggleButton = new JToggleButton("On");
        ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) {
                int state = itemEvent.getStateChange();
                if (state == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    Switch = "On";
                    toggleButton.setText("Off");
                    afk.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                } else {
                    Switch = "Off";
                    afk.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
                    toggleButton.setText("On");
                }
            }
        };
        toggleButton.addItemListener(itemListener);



        text.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        text.setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        toggleButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        toggleButton.setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        afk.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
        afk.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        afk.setSize(500, 500);
        afk.add(text);
        afk.add(toggleButton);
        afk.setVisible(true);




        while (Switch.equals("On")){
        Random diceRoller = new Random();

            int RN = diceRoller.nextInt(4) + 1;
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            System.out.println(RN);


            if (RN == 1) {
                try {

                    Robot robot = new Robot();
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);


                } catch (AWTException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (RN == 2) {
                    try {

                        Robot robot = new Robot();
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);

                    } catch (AWTException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
             if (RN == 3) {
                        try {

                            Robot robot = new Robot();
                            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
                            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
                            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);

                        } catch (AWTException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
             if (RN == 4) {
                            try {

                                Robot robot = new Robot();
                                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
                                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
                                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);

                            } catch (AWTException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

}






    }

class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
System.exit(1);
System.out.println("YOU PRESSED");

}}}}
```

Comment: Please include the compiler error in your question and limit yourself to one question per post. You should also create am [MCVE] (with emphasis on **minimal**).

Comment: Just a note: no statements following `System.exit()` will be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your `Switch` variable global by moving it on top level of the class, in this way you will solve the issue.

A variable defined in a method and accessed by an anonymous inner class must be final. This happens because in anonymous classes you don't have the parent scope and you can't know if it changes the variable. By making it final you guarantee that the changes are only done in the scope of the inner class. By making it global you make it visible in general.

Comment: This fixes the problem, but you do not explain the problem in the first place (i.e. why the compiler is complaining) and why the solution fixes the problem.

Comment: @Turing85 I added some info.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the compiler is complaining about `JFrame afk`.

You are using it inside the internal class but it's not a final variable.

The simplest solution is to provide it as a constructor variable of your inner class and use it there. You'll get rid of the error that way.